# Why I am not able to refresh dialog box with WM_NCPAINT, but working fine with WM_SIZE?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I am having dialog box application in MFC. To refresh view on dialog box we are using `WM_NCPAINT`, it does call `OnNCPaint`, but sometimes view is not getting refreshed. Behaviour is not always reproducible. Same behaviour is happening with `WM_PAINT` also.

When we use `SendMessage(WM_SIZE)`, behaviour is not reproducible, and working as expected.

Before checking in the code, I wanted to make sure, should I use `WM_SIZE` instead of `WM_NCPAINT` or `WM_PAINT`, because it is working fine with it.

Comment: Why downvote? What wrong I have done?

Comment: *"behaviour is not reproducible, and working as expected."*, *"`SendMessage(WM_SIZE)`"*, etc. There's quite a bit of objectionable stuff in the question.

Comment: There is not a single *WM_SIZE* message. Windows sends a banch of other messages too for a resize to happen. You just cross your fingers for it to work. But crossing fingers is not a good programming method. The same with *WM_PAINT*. There is a proper way. See the answers.

Answer (score 6):

No, you shouldn't use either of those.

To indicate that a window needs to be re-painted, call the [`InvalidateRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. That is what you probably should be using.

To force a window to be re-painted *now*, call the [`UpdateWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145167%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Either way, don't start sending random messages and praying that the side effect of one of those messages is to have the window re-painted.

Answer (score 5):

If I understand the question correctly, you are sending WM messages to trigger a repaint of your dialog box? The correct way to do this is to invalidate the client area.

You could either use the Windows API function `InvalidateRect()` directly, or the `CWnd::Invalidate()` method within MFC.